# SASS get border color from another parameter?

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way to get color from another parameter in SASS?

For example: 
I've got 10 buttons, and each of them has different `background-color` value. Each of them should also have a `border-top` of 0.5em, but it has to match the color of `background-color`. So is there a way to write something like `border-top: 10px solid $background-color;`? I know that $ stands for variable that is declared by myself, but you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Read up on the @extend part of SASS. There are also many tutorials on youtube about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with built-in functions and syntax only. It has been requested as a feature many times before, for example in 2012 ([#559](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/559)) and 2015 ([#1603](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1603)). The latter issue was closed with the following comment:

> If you want to share a value, extract it as a mixin or as a placeholder. The encourages you to very clearly show what aspects of an implementation are shared and what are "private" to the class.

If you still don't want to repeat yourself when using the same value for different properties, have a look at [issue #109](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/109) and [lifesaver-sass](https://github.com/whaaaley/lifesaver-sass). It provides a mixin to do the following:

```
.primary-button {
    border-top: 10px solid;
    @include save(background-color border-color #aaa);
}
```

Output:

```
.primary-button {
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-color #aaa;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some kind of interpolation as seen here: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Two-handy-and-advanced-SASS-features-and-their-limitations. I am not super familiar with that technique. I would use a mixin like my example below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
```

**SASS**

```
@mixin set-color($color) {
    border-top: solid 1px #{$color};
    background-color: #{$color}; 
}

.box {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.box-1 {
    @include set-color("blue");
}

.box-2 {
    @include set-color("red");
}
```